# Create new column if all values in a column list are zero

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column which looks at a list of columns (colList) and returns zero if every value in those columns is zero and 1 for all else.

colList = ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3']

```
Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
    0        0        0      1
    10       8        1      3
    1        0        0      5
Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 newcol
0        0        0      1     0
10       8        1      3     1
1        0        0      5     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.any` with `axis==1`:

```
df["newcol"] = df[colList].any(1).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  newcol
0       0       0       0       1       0
1      10       8       1       3       1
2       1       0       0       5       1
```

Comment: What if I'm checking for the presence of 'yes' in these columns and my value in the new column needs to be 'True' if any column has a 'yes'? thanks